# jQuery not working on SharePoint site

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, javascript, jquery

I have calendar webpart with list of leave and I need to calculate leave time under the table. Under calendar table I put script editor webpart with table:

```
<table id="Total">
<thead><tr>Totals</tr></thead>
<tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

Then I put Jquery code:

```
<script src="http://XXX/siteassets/java/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script><script type="text/javascript">
var totals = [];
$('#\\{A7F3A569-11ED-4EEC-B9CE-5626CFDA8427\\}-\\{750A17C0-4BF2-48B8-8FCA-749DDBCF5D87\\} tbody tr').each(function(e) {      
var tds= $(this).find('td');
var index = $(tds[1]).text();
var Numberofhord = parseFloat($(tds[2]).text().replace(",","."), 10);
if (totals[index] == undefined)
totals[index] = { Numberofhord: 0 };
totals[index].Numberofhord += Numberofhord;
});
for (var key in totals)
$('#Total tbody').append('<tr><td>'+key+'</td><td>'+totals[key].Numberofhord+'</td></tr>')
</script>
```

All works great on jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/qha5jr3b/ but dont work on my site.

I have SharePoint Foundation 2013. I put `jquery-3.1.1.min.js` to siteassets folder. I have tried to put script in js file and attach link to calendar webpart ([link](http://geekswithblogs.net/SoYouKnow/archive/2011/07/28/a-dummies-guide-to-sharepoint-and-jqueryndashgetting-started.aspx)), also tried to use:

```
$(document).ready(function ()
```

and

```
$(window).bind("load", function()
```

Still nothing, jquery work only when I put static html table on script editor webpart or when I edit calendar webpart.

Any idea why my JQuery code is not working?
Thank You!

Comment: check Console, if any errors are showing

Comment: If you say it works in Edit-Mode and not in Display mode then double double check and then check again if that hardcoded GUID actually exists in Display mode

Comment: It works but only sometimes when i start to edit page, then start to change some properties of calendar webpart. Sript works great when I put static  table with ID of webpart.

Comment: What do you mean with "It works but only sometimes"? Only on page load and not when adding/editing items?

Comment: It works only when I editing page next I change calendar webpart properties. Cosole show ony two alerts - DOM7011 disable back navigation caching SEC7115 :visited and :link styles can only differ by color

Comment: If you say it works sometimes, then its in (async) loading issue. Wrap your code in a function and set an onload="yourfunction()" event on the script tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After hours I found problem, I pasted script like this:

```
<script src="http://xxx/siteassets/java/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://xxx/siteassets/java/su.js></script>
```

After change to:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://xxx/siteassets/java/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://xxx/siteassets/java/su.js></script>
```

All works! Thank you anyways!

Answer (score 0):

Open the source code of your site SharePoint, and locate the script tag, then try to open the script link in a new window, normally the script should be displayed ([like this one](http://gostonet.com/vendor/jquery.min.js)), otherwise fix the link in the script tag.

Another thing, make sure the browser does not block JavaScript scripts

Keep me informed

Comment: Im using IE and chrome. I have no option in IE to open in new tab but in chrome when I click open in new tab its downloading js file from server.